# how to access external service using the minikube host's public ip address

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, minikube

I've set up a **minikube** cluster on an Azure's Ubuntu instance that exposes an external service on the IP: `192.168.49.2:30000`

`curl 192.168.49.2:30000` returns the desired output.
How can I access this service using a browser on my local machine using the azure host public IP address ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Explanation:

---

#### EDIT:

OK, I see that **docker** driver by default uses `192.168.49.2` IP address:

```
azureuser@minikube:~$ minikube service web --url
http://192.168.49.2:31527
```

so most probably you've used this one. Although the further explanation is based on **virtualbox** example it can be fully applied also in this case, with the only difference that **minikube** runs as an isolated docker container and not as a VM. But if you run `docker ps` on your **Azure VM instance** you'll see only one container, named `minikube`:

```
azureuser@minikube:~$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                                                                                      NAMES
af68ab219c6c        gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.14   "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   53 minutes ago      Up 53 minutes       127.0.0.1:32771->22/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32770->2376/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32769->5000/tcp, 127.0.0.1:32768->8443/tcp   minikube
```

Only after running:

```
azureuser@minikube:~$ minikube ssh
```

and then:

```
docker@minikube:~$ docker ps
```

you'll see both the container running by your **app `Pod`** as well as **kubernetes control plane components**. The list is quite long so I won't put it here.

But it shows that your **kubernetes** cluster is in practice isolated in a very similar way from your **Azure VM** host as in case when it runs in a **nested VM**. The key point here is that minikube cluster's network is isolated from host VM network and `NodePort` Service is accessible only on the external IP of a VM or `minikube` docker container, not exposing any port on any of host VM network interfaces.

---

I've reproduced your case, assuming that you started your minikube with [virtualbox driver](http://%20https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/virtualbox/), so please correct me if my assumption was wrong. You could've started it this way:

```
minikube start --driver=virtualbox
```

or simply:

```
minikube start
```

If you've installed **VirtualBox** on your **minikube** vm, it will be also automatically detected and `virtualbox` driver will be used.

OK, so let's pause for a moment at this point and take a closer look what such approach implies.

Your **minikube** runs inside your **Azure VM** but it doesn't run directly on it. Nested virtualization is used and your minikube kubernetes cluster actually runs on a vm inside another vm.

So if you've exposed your `Deployment` using `NodePort` service, it makes it available on the external IP address of **minikube vm** (which is nested vm). But this IP is external only from the perspective of this vm.

Let's ssh into our **Azure VM** and run:

```
azureuser@minikube:~$ minikube service web --url
http://192.168.99.100:31955
```

Your service name and address will be different but I'm showing it just to illustrate the idea.

Then run:

```
azureuser@minikube:~$ ip -4 a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 10.0.0.4/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: vboxnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.99.1/24 brd 192.168.99.255 scope global vboxnet0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you can see `192.168.99.100` is reachable via `vboxnet0` network interface as it's part of `192.168.99.0/24` network, used by virtualbox vm.

Therefore there are no means for it to be reachable without using additional port forwarding, not only on the external IP of the **Azure VM** but on any of its internal network interfaces. `NodePort` service exposes the `Deployment` only on the external IP of the nested **VirtualBox VM** (or other hypervisor), which is reachable from **Azure VM** host but it's not exposed on any of it's network interfaces so it cannot be reached from outside either.

#### Solution:

Did I just say port forwarding ? Fortunately `kubectl` makes it fairly easy task. If you haven't installed it so far on your **Azure VM**, please do it as `minikube kubectl` may not work. You can use for it the following command:

```
kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/<service-name> 8080:8080
```

which will forward the traffic destined to any of **Azure VM** addresses (also the public one) to your `Service`, which in this case doesn't even have to be of `NodePort` type, `ClusterIP` will also work.

Caveat: To be able to bind to a well known port such as `80` you need to run this command as `root`. If you use registered ports, starting from `1024` such as `8080` you don't need root access. So after running:

```
root@minikube:~# kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/web 80:8080
```

You should be able to access your app without any problems by using the external IP address of your **Azure VM**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the thorough answer. I have used the docker driver not the virtualbox one. I've tried the port forwarding, however I didn't use the --address argument.

Comment: is there a more "robust" solution than `kubectl port-forward` ? What if the port-forwarding get closed for any reason ?

Comment: Yes, not using nested virtualization and setting up your k8s cluster directly on VM instances in the cloud. Note that **Minikube** is not meant to be used in production environments anyway. Take a look at [driver none (bare-metal)](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/) which _"allows advanced minikube users to skip VM creation, allowing minikube to be run on a user-supplied VM"_.

Comment: thanks mario, so I have a computer which runs on Fedora 33 (linux), I can manage to run a minikube cluster on it with `--driver=none` and reach my NodePort services directly through my public-ip:node-port (public ip provided by my internet provider), right ?

Comment: Exactly, because in this case you don't run your **Minikube** in a nested VM or container but directly on your Fedora machine/VM, so your `NodePort` doesn't need to be additionally forwarded anywhere as it exposes your `Deployment` directly on this host. It's a bit harder to set up and that's why it is recommended for advanced users only. But you need to make sure this public IP is assigned to your machine and it's not just your home router's public IP. If you see this public IP when you run `ip -4 a` on your machine, it can be used by your `NodePort`.

Comment: thanks for detailled info, also if I want to aim for production environment, can I setup kubernetes cluster on this machine ? I guess I need to setup 3 VM to have 2 nodes and 1 worker ? I mean is it a viable option ? I don't wish to use cloud provider

Comment: Yes, it's possible but you may need to set additional port forwarding on your router. Take a look at [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/). It doesn't have to be 3 node cluster. You may need to create only one master and one worker node.

Comment: @mario Thanks. The most helpful detailed answer I've found. Can you also clarify how to keep the port forwarding working in the background? I've seen the use of the `&` operator to have it work as a process, but it stopped after a little while on its own, is this normal?

Comment: Running it in background is not very reliable solution. Some people may be tempted to run it in `screen`, but I wouldn't recommend it either. For such things you have `systemd` :-) Read about creating custom systemd units if you're not very familiar with them and take a look at [this example](https://gist.github.com/gartnera/31cafc3d0dcdfb5bf0f5a2192e3fbe2c). As you can see it uses `socat` for port forwarding but you can also use `kubectl` with the required parameters.

Comment: @mario: I run command `kubectl port-forward --address 0.0.0.0 service/web-service 80:80` but it only success with `curl localhost:80`, it fail with `curl 192.168.49.2:80`, I get that ip from `minikube ip`.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue that I was receiving the private IP address 192.168.49.2..... So the port which I have exposed was accessible within the EC2 instance using curl request, but when I have added that port in Inbound rules of security group then also using the public IPv4 address of system with port number, it was not accessible over the internet....
For Eg. --> **13.402.12.111:30009**     {:Port Exposed}

So for this I used **Portforwarding**....Thanks to the solution of mario....

I came to know two things....

1. When service is hosted on localhost on EC2 instance say..... **localhost:49160** then this is **accessible** over the internet when this port is added to security group...
2. When service is hosted on Private IP on EC2 instance say.... **192.168.49.2:49160** then this is **not accessible** over the internet when this port is added to security group... use Port Forwarding for this...